# Инициализация констант с помощью функции

Tags: c++

Не могу проинициализировать `LENGTH_STRING`, компилятор ругается на последнюю строчку "`error C2131: выражение не определяется константой`", причем если сделать `LENGTH_STRING=100`, то все работает. Есть ли способ инициализировать `LENGTH_STRING` через предыдущие константы?

```
#include <climits>

inline int getT(unsigned int x) {
    int p = 0;
    while (x > 10) {
        p++;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return p;
}

const unsigned int N = USHRT_MAX - 1;               
const int T = getT(N);                              
const int LENGTH = 1000;                                
const int LENGTH_STRING = (T+1)*LENGTH;
```

Comment: VC++ 2015 компилирует без проблем.

Comment: Уточните компилятор и стандарт C++. g++ не обламывается.

Comment: @PinkTux Я использую Visual Studio 2015 Community с ее стандартным компилятором "из коробки".

Comment: У меня в файле cpp тоже работает, а в хедере - ругается

Comment: А constexp не поможет в данном примере?

Comment: @user228430 *"У меня в файле cpp тоже работает, а в хедере - ругается"* - ну надо же сразу в вопросе давать всю информацию, а не по капельке!

Answer (score 1):

Определите функцию, например, следующим образом

```
constexpr unsigned  int getT( unsigned int n ) 
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    return 1 + ( n / Base ? getT( n / Base ) : 0);
}
```